# How to make AppBarLayout Drawable background to be spread over the status bar?

Tags: android, xml, layout, statusbar, android-appbarlayout

I'm trying to achieve AppbarLayout with background, inside the AppbarLayout to have a static Toolbar, under the the Toolbar i'm using a CollpasingToolBar that now contains a Toolbar and later supposed to include also a Custom View that it's content will be scaled according to scrolling position, and in the bottom of the AppBarLayout i'm using a TabLayout.
The issue i can't resolve is: i want that the AppbarLayout *Drawable* will be also be spread over the status bar, currently i failed to achieve this.
I'm attaching the xml layout and also a screen shot:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds = "true"
    android:statusBarColor="@android:color/transparent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:background="@drawable/winterscenery"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">




        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent"

            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>



        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="One" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Two" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Three" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/content_text_one" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/content_button" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/content_text_two" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

After editing Manifest file :

```
        <activity android:name=".ExitUntilCollapsedActivity" android:theme="@style/JustTryStyle" />
```

And creating the *JustTryStyle* style:

```
    <style name="JustTryStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

I got the following apperance:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your theme you need to add

```xml
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

**Edit:**
Add these two to the theme your activity uses as defined in the AndroidManifest.
If other activities also use use this theme but should not have the transparent navigationbar then you need to extend it and update your AndroidManifest accordingly.

**Edit 2:** try adding `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` instead or additionally

**Edit 3:** also add `fitSystemWindow=true` to constraintlayout and appbar

Comment: Hi, thanks! Which theme? Should i extend the theme that is set for *AppBarLAyout* and add the two attributes you just wrote? Cause i made it and it didn't help me :( ..
 Also these attributes available only for min '21' and i prefer the app will work against '19 version, so i have two issues here

Comment: i made what you told me:
<style name="JustTryStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        
    </style>
and i got a color that is look like the color of my NestedView

Comment: @Eitanos30 could you add a screenshot of this and your complete new layout and style to the question?

Comment: i can. But isn't a convenience solution that will be relevant also for  lower versions?

Comment: try updated answer as it is what the offical docs say

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219637/discussion-between-mcslinplay-and-eitanos30).